# reactstrap: DropdownItem not rendering inside map method of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, interpolation, array.prototype.map, react-table-v6

ISSUE: data inside `DropdownItem` is not rendering but, all console logs work.

and this same problem is also present inside the table columns.

**PS: I strongly think this is about interpolation and react in general and not react-table**

this is my complete code [image: Edit black-frost-j9zuv]

and below are the relevant snippets.

not sure, where I am going wrong.

**dropdown**

```
<Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggleDropdown}>
                    <DropdownToggle caret>Ships</DropdownToggle>
                    {measurementsData.map((measurementData) => {
                      console.log(" md:", measurementData);
                      console.log(" md.sites:", measurementData.sites);
                      console.log(
                        " md.sites[0].uuid:",
                        measurementData.sites[0].uuid
                      );
                      console.log(
                        " md.sites[0].siteName:",
                        measurementData.sites[0].siteName
                      );
                      {
                        measurementData.sites.map((site) => {
                          console.log(" site.siteName:", site.siteName);
                          return (
                            <DropdownMenu key={site.uuid}>
                              <DropdownItem>
                                {site.siteName}
                                <DropdownItem divider />
                              </DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu>
                          );
                        });
                      }
                    })}
                  </Dropdown>
```

**table columns**

```
  columns = [
    // * embedding checkbox
    {
      Header: "Select",
      Cell: (row) => (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={this.state.checked[row.index]}
          checked={this.state.checked[row.index]}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      Header: "System",
      accessor: "sites.systems.systemName",
    },
    {
      Header: "Measurement",
      accessor: "sites.systems.measurements.name",
    },
    {
      Header: "Min",
      accessor: "sites.systems.measurements.min",
    },
    {
      Header: "Max",
      accessor: "sites.systems.measurements.max",
    },
    {
      Header: "Avg",
      accessor: "sites.systems.measurements.average",
    },
    {
      Header: "Last",
      accessor: "sites.systems.measurements.last",
    },
    {
      Header: "Bar",
      accessor: "sites.systems.measurements.buckets.values",
      Cell: this.MyCell,
    },
  ];
```

The Last column of the table has a pie chart, below code is for that.

```
MyCell({
    value,
    columnProps: {
      rest: { someFunc },
    },
  }) {
    const data = {
      labels: value.map((val, idx) => {
        return idx;
      }),
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: [
            "#ff8779",
            "#2a84e9",
            "#e2e2e2",
            "#ff8779",
            "#2a84e9",
            "#e2e2e2",
          ],
          data: value,
        },
      ],
    };

    return <Pie data={data} />;
  }
```

Comment: The problem seems to be this line: `import ReactTable from "react-table";` because `ReactTable` is undefined. According to the [docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/5aa2b41d16386e80d14275134e49166a930312cf/docs/quickstart.md#final-result) you're going to use a `useTable` hook and `<table>`, not the code you have.

Comment: `ReactTable` is not undefined. If you look at the codeSandbox, you'll see it's there inside the render method.

Comment: No, sorry, you have to figure this out yourself. I linked you to tons of code examples.

Comment: apologies for the trouble but I have no clue why codeSandbox is not rendering the table. the table does render on my machine

Comment: that's why 1) Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f2b21927-0025-49c5-9155-d7cea76a0da0' from origin 'https://1s834.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. and 2) you are using react-table 7.2.2. please switch to 6.8.6 for example. version 7 has different approach.

Comment: mocky.io is api mocking online service which I am using to create api URL. just now it has started giving this error. but, I am having this issue before that. I am using "react-table": "6.11.5" version. Verified from my package.json file.

Comment: PS: I strongly think this is about interpolation and react in general and not react-table

Comment: @Apostolos codeSandbox is rendering the table now. I have updated its version based on what I am using. might wanna give it another look.  also, feel free to mess around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to put `DropDownMenu` outside the map function

second you need to somehow flatten your array

```
var merged = measurementsData.map(md => md.sites);
merged = [].concat(...merged);
```

and then

```
              <DropdownMenu>
                {merged.map(site => {
                  return (
                    <DropdownItem key={site.siteName}>
                      {site.siteName}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  );
                })}
              </DropdownMenu>
```

this should work.

Comment: not really. check out the screenshot https://imgur.com/ZzPhYSC Console logged it and it does give `site.name` but, it's not rendering it

Comment: check my link https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-proskuriakova-ivr8m

Comment: i have removed MyCell stuff because it kept throwing errors.

Comment: thanks. it worked. MyCell also has a similar issue.

Comment: done. but I am facing the rest of the 2 problems. table rows and MyCell

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `version 6` of `react-table`, according to [docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#usage):

```
$ yarn add react-table-v6

# or NPM

$ npm install react-table-v6
```

and then you gotta import the following items:

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table-v6'
import 'react-table-v6/react-table.css'
```

for accessors of react-table header you need to change them to make sure they use the value of first index of array:

```
{
  Header: "System",
  accessor: "sites[0].systems[0].systemName" // note that these are arrays not objects 
},
```

and that goes for all of the header items.

Comment: codeSandbox is rendering the table now. I have updated its version based on what I am using. might wanna give it another look.  also, feel free to mess around.

Comment: I understand that part but, I need to render all the entries, not just the ones at `[0] index`. so how do I do that?

Comment: you want to generate a row based on every available combination?